# Add custom field output to Structure row

Tags: structure

Using Structure to manage a bunch of content and I'd love to show the value of a single custom field to the right of the title. It is just a number field to identify a piece of artwork. I imagine there may be a hook or something to grab onto within Structure and grab the value, but I was wondering if anyone had done this before and had any advice to offer?

I do know that I could go the route of Zenbu to show more customized information in a standard channel entries display, but I'd prefer to keep my client in the Structure world if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need an [Extension](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extensions.html) that taps into the structure_index_view_data hook:

```
function activate_extension() {
    $hooks = array(
        "structure_index_view_data" => "customise_structure"
    );

    foreach ($hooks as $hook => $method) {
        $data = array(
            'class' => __CLASS__,
            'method' => $method,
            'hook' => $hook,
            'settings' => "",
            'priority' => 10,
            'version' => $this->version,
            'enabled' => 'y'
        );
        $this->EE->db->insert($this->EE->db->dbprefix . 'extensions', $data);
    }//###   End of foreach   ###
}//###   End of activate_extension function
```

Then in your customise_structure method:

```
function customise_structure($data) {
    if ($this->extensions->end_script === TRUE)
        return $data;
    if ($this->EE->extensions->last_call !== FALSE)
    $data = $this->EE->extensions->last_call;

    foreach($data["data"] as $tab_id => $content) {
        foreach($content as $eid => $page) {
            //Use $page['entry_id'] to get the entry ID
            //Use $page['title'] to append and customise the row display

            ...

        }//###   End of foreach   ###
    }//###   End of foreach   ###
    return $data;
}//###   End of customise_structure function
```

Using the entry_id you could run a query for each loop getting the custom field then appending it to $page["title"] with relevant spacing or span to indent or style further.

Be warned though, do a query per loop would be consuming, you'd be better to do an initial loop building the entry_id list, then build a single SQL getting just the single custom field you require for all the entries.

This should be enough to get you up and running on building your own extension.

Comment: Peter, huge thanks for taking the time to run through this. I really appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a normal channel tag to show any custom fields you want. If it's not data that is part of the current page URL, you'll need to specify the entry_id and use dynamic="no".

Comment: Travis - @noahkuhn wants to customise the Control Panel view of Structure, not frontend. I imagine an extension could be used to tap into structure_index_view_data hook...?